# How to use IntDef in a kotlin data class constructor

Tags: android, class, kotlin, constructor

I have this data class and I want to use IntDef instead of just and Int.

```
import androidx.annotation.IntDef
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class Attendee(
    @SerializedName("id") val mId: Long,
    @SerializedName("AttendeeType") val mAttendeeType: AttendeeType,
    @SerializedName("Status") val mStatus: AttendeeStatus) {


@IntDef(ATTENDEE_TYPE_USER, ATTENDEE_TYPE_CONTACT, ATTENDEE_TYPE_EXTERNAL_USER)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class AttendeeType

@IntDef(ATTENDEE_STATUS_ACCEPTED, ATTENDEE_STATUS_DECLINED, ATTENDEE_STATUS_TENTATIVE, ATTENDEE_STATUS_NOT_ANSWERED)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class AttendeeStatus

companion object {
    const val ATTENDEE_TYPE_USER = 1
    const val ATTENDEE_TYPE_CONTACT = 2
    const val ATTENDEE_TYPE_EXTERNAL_USER = 3

    const val ATTENDEE_STATUS_ACCEPTED = 1
    const val ATTENDEE_STATUS_DECLINED = 2
    const val ATTENDEE_STATUS_TENTATIVE = 3
    const val ATTENDEE_STATUS_NOT_ANSWERED = 4
}
}
```

The main problem now, is that I can't create a simple `Attendee` this way:
`Attendee(10000, 1, 2)` -> compiler shows: `The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Attendee.AttendeeType`

Question 1:
I would like to be able to use IntDef in this case, to be sure that I can only use the values inside them. Is it possible?

Question 2:
What's the difference between `val mAttendeeType: AttendeeType` and `@AttendeeType val mAttendeeType: Int`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the point of that?  Why isn't AtendeeType an enum?  Why are you bringing in weird and confusing annotations when a simple feature of the language does what you want?  I get it if you were using it as a bitfield (whether that technique should be used outside of direct hardware manipulation is a different argument), but there's no good reason here.

Comment: @GabeSechan because IntDefs are much more efficient than enums
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35787531/3683195

Comment: THey really aren't.  That piece of "advice" was hotly debated and mostly considered to be a bad idea 10 years ago when it was new.  Its definitely something that's outdated now.  It should not be used.  They also don't have the advantages in code correctness that enums have, such as type correctness.

Comment: To put it another way-  you have an app that by default, will use 50 MB just from resources and data loaded at startup.  the total difference, if you used IntDef over enum everywhere might be 5K.  And that's likely a huge overestimate.  Nobody uses this technique.

Comment: Also, ProGuard/R8 converts enums to Ints in most cases for you anyway.